# How can I stop values being outputted immediately in Forth?

Tags: stack, forth

Using [SwiftForth](https://www.forth.com/swiftforth/#Overview), I am currently looking at methods for measuring the time it takes for a word to be executed. I am using the words 'counter' and then 'timer' in the form:

```
counter insert_word_here timer
```

This immediately outputs the time in microseconds that it takes to run the word. Is there a way I can prevent this integer from being outputted immediately, so that I can store it in the stack?

Comment: It looks like a system specific thing. What Forth system do you use?

Comment: It was using SwiftForth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`timer` in SwiftForth is implemented something like

```
: timer  \ t0 -- ;
  counter swap - u.
;
```

Simply define a word without the `u.` and the elapsed time in milliseconds is left on the stack.

```
: timer-ms \ t0 -- t-elapsed
  counter swap -
;
```

I don't have SwiftForth, but timer was defined as an example on the page I found. I think this should work, but I can't test it.

Comment: In fact in the copy of SwiftForth I have, the `timer-ms` part in your code I think already exists and is called `(TIMER)`.